# A function $N_p$ helps defining a metric $\phi_p$ and spheres with this metric give numbers divisible by $p^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I have the following problem:

Let $p$ be a prime number and $N_p : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$N_p (a) = \begin{cases} 2^{-n} & \text{if}\  a \neq 0, n\in\mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0\} : p^n | a\  \text{and} \ p^{n+1}\nmid a \\
0 & \text{if}\  a=0 \end{cases}$$

1. Show $\phi_p : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $ given by $\phi_p (a,b) = N_p (a-b)$ is a metric on  $\mathbb{Z}$
2. Show that the sphere with the $\phi_p$ metric and with center on the origin and radius $\frac{1}{8}$ ,i.e. $S_{\frac{1}{8}} (0) $, is the subset of all integers divisible by $p^3$ but not by $p^4$. Describe the sphere.

I absolutely do not understand where to begin with this one. I can see that, for example, in the second problem the sphere has something to do with $\frac{1}{p^n}$ and depending on that we get some kind of divisibility. Thus, with a radius one ($n=0$) we can get all the integers. In the first point, problems begin with $a$ and $b$, I don't get if they can be completely arbitrary to satisfy that $\phi_p $  is a metric on $\mathbb{Z}$. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Did you swap the order of the does not divide in the definition? It looks like you're trying to grab the exponent of the highest power of the prime that goes into the number

Comment: For 1,  you need to prove the positive semidefinite,  (That it's almways nonnegative and is 0 if and only if the points are the same,  trivial),  symmetric (trivial) and the triangle inequality (Nontrivial)

Comment: @Alan, indeed I got things mixed with the non divide, thanks for the remark. And, yes, the third axiom of metric (triangle inequality) is always the tricky one. The thing is that I get very confused on how to interpret $N_p$

Comment: $p$ is a fixed prime,  so you will have a different function and different metric for each prime. $N_p$ takes in numbers and reports out the highest prime that goes into it in the form of an exponent of one half.   So for instance,  $N_3(18)=\frac 1 4$ because the highest power of $3$ that goes into $18$ is 2.    $N_3(19)=1$,  $N_3(0)=0$.  Basicall-y the more copies of the prime that goes into the number, the smaller the output.

Comment: Oh...I'm getting the picture now. Indeed as you commented, the triangle inequality will be the most tricky property of metric to prove. In the second part of the problem, how can a sphere define all integers divisible? Does the radius changes or it has to be something regarding being on the complex plane?

Comment: Well, two numbers will be close to each other if their difference has a bunch of the same prime factors.  Part 2 appears to be wrong to me though, as $N_2(16-0)=N_2(16)=2^{-4}$ would be in that sphere.  It looks to me like the sphere should be all the points who have exactly 1, 2, or 3 copies of that prime as a factor.